# Неправильно отображается латиница (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, кодировка, windows-10, шрифты

Вопрос не по программированию. Сорян)) просто не знаю кого спросить.

Пока что проблему заметил только в одной программе. Можно было бы подумать, что всё дело в ней, но на всех остальных ПК никаких проблем не возникает. Проблемы с отображением символов наблюдаются только на моем компьютере. Мало того, сразу после установки системы всё было нормально.
Причем, приложение на английском языке и, следовательно, проблема возникла с латиницей. Кирилица тут ни при чем.

Как решить проблему?
(переустановка Windows - не вариант)

[image: Демонстрация проблемы с отображением надписей]

Comment: Смотрите, какой шрифт использует программа. Походу, он битый.

Comment: А как узнать какой там шрифт?

Comment: Посмотрите с помощью, например, Sysinternals ProcessExplorer. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: Большое спасибо! 
Оказалось, шрифт Segoe UI куралесил. 
Заменил его на родной (из образа винды) и всё стало как надо.
Еще раз спасибо!